# CouchDB key always matches

Tags: couchdb

I'm looking to query my CouchDB in such a way that some of the fields in a document can be wildcards that match any key request.

Example:

```js
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.some_field, doc);
}
```

`?key=100` would match both the document with *some_field* of *100* and of *some_field* value like ***.

Is this possible? Is there a hack to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [CouchDB documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation?action=show&redirect=ViewCollation#String_Ranges) you can do:

```
?startkey="key"&endkey="key\ufff0"
```

to match *key**.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, the author wants not a query with a wildcard. He needs rows of a view to have wildcards in their keys. OT: thanks for your work on couchdb, etc. :)

Comment: Right, I need any key I pass in to end up matching to some wildcard key stored in the database. I know it probably sounds odd... But its for a package manager to be able to ask for all packages compiled for the system properties of X, Y and Z but some packages are generic and may match on X and Y but not have Z however they have the generic field marked like *.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood the question then. You can use a POST request to the view to get a logical OR for many keys if your POST body looks like this: `{"keys": ["key1", "key2", ...]}` See http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API

Comment: Hmm, so that would actually work if I could somehow combine it with start and end keys. Since I still also need wildcards in the keys.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-523 -- But I guess you, Jan, already know about this :)

Comment: (should be a backslash, not forward slash: \ufff0)

Answer (score 0):

From Couchdb [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views):

> CouchDB actually stores the
>   [key,docid] pair as the key in the
>   btree. This means that:
>
> - you always know which document the key and value came from (it's exposed as the 'id' field in the view result)
> - view rows with equal keys sort by increasing docid.

So I don't think that wildcard fields used as a part of a key are possible because they are sorted. Suppose they are possible. Then if you try to query a key range from a view, rows with a wildcard will be returned with any key range. That means that they are everywhere. But that's impossible because they are sorted. That is a row with a wildcard is placed between a pair of other rows one of which has a greater key and the other a smaller one.

Comment: Yeah, I guess if there was somehow to do an OR though that'd work. like 100 OR *. I may have to use couchdb-lucene.

Comment: Using two requests may serve as a workaround: first request for your key (?key=100) and the second for wildcarded rows. If course wildcarded rows would need to have adjacent keys.

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation?action=show&redirect=ViewCollation#String_Ranges says it is all possible :)

Comment: @Jan If I understood the question right then -1 to my answer is excessive. However I ought to mention this collations based tricks.

Comment: got it wrong, see comments on my answer. Not sure how SO lets me remove the -1.

Comment: @Jan Pressing the button again should undo.

Comment: I tried, but I get a warning "You last voted on this answer Jan 17 at 11:23 Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited"